Can't connect Fly.io to external SQL Server database
I have a website uploaded to fly.io that connects to a SQL Server database on a different server (fly doesn't support SQL Server as far as I can tell). I have set up a username and password to allow external access to it and it works fine in Docker when run locally.
However when I upload it to Fly I get the following error:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host -server ip- , port 1433 has failed.

I get that it is saying it can't connect to the database but I'm not sure if the problem is at Fly's side or the database server's side.
What do I need to do to allow the connection from fly to the external database?

The problem is likely that you need to open ports on the sql server server side to outside for fly.io to connect, which is a bad idea because it makes your server insecure. You should use proper stack, like cloud db
